# Getting issue while integrating CCAvenue in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ccavenue

I am not getting `rsa` value while using CCAvenue.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be `rsa` deallocated, check and debug value of `rsa` or `rsa` is not initialized.

Comment: I have already checked but i am getting `rsa` value to NULL.

Comment: then `RSA_size(rsa);` will give bad access.

Comment: So what i have to do?

Comment: Debug and check which values are `nil` and why? then handle accordingly.

Comment: Did you reslved this issue

Answer (score 0):

make format of rsa as

```
rsaKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n%@\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n",rsaKey];
```

RSA Key :

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl6I3oQD5M23Q+c/2pMZnn5NbnfbF+YZg RG1YRhLmkBGKGBa5XsrgbseQbZi3wQ4sQz5kp01vKDC56A7ItM9Qy4uQwCXP0gTgtAjxZKmwJe9I axccP+A8QNNbnFpiBj9pmjc9yKudvsn0lIURe7b1t1TwnH02sqRIYgBzUReo7yqp9E0IlrOK7bjm 47OZhedhc5AJ6IQqMq3+CUOobocT8xyXTXukg21m3eCDjlgaaRzdG13rJmPofI2UVsO3dFgnplBp nHom5QFQ2q8cV8LzqLnN6o5uRB4jr7wWvAoX+e+dGY6lC+i3HaNnGox5e4nJ5lrO7I8upbfxKeID TvHCOQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes when there is issue with the php code that you put in merchant server which is registered in ccavenue dashboard.

if the problem still exists you need to call ccavenue and whitelist your ip.

Then you will get a proper rsa key and your issue will be gone